# SQL Server Show Results when Record not found

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to get SQL to list not found when a machine name lookup is not in the database. I have the query working but I need to integrate it into C# where I have other queries. As it stands it is a lot more convoluted than I want it to be, I am guessing there is a much more intelligent and concise why of having the SQL achieve the same result.

```sql
DECLARE @myHostCount as INT
DECLARE @myHostName1 as Varchar(50);
DECLARE @myHostName2  as Varchar(50) = 'Machine220054';
DECLARE @myHostCount1 as INT
DECLARE @myHostName3 as Varchar(50);
DECLARE @myHostName4  as Varchar(50) = 'Machine22054';

SET @myHostCount1 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db_owner.host WHERE name LIKE '%Machine22054%')

SET @myHostName3 = (SELECT Name FROM db_owner.host WHERE name LIKE '%Machine22054%')

SET @myHostCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db_owner.host WHERE name LIKE '%Machine220054%')

SET @myHostName1 = (SELECT Name FROM db_owner.host WHERE name LIKE '%Machine220054%')

SELECT
    CASE
       WHEN @myHostCount = 1 THEN 'Found'
       WHEN @myHostCount = 0 THEN 'Not Found'
    END AS 'Result', 
    @myHostName2 AS 'HostName'

UNION

SELECT
    CASE
       WHEN @myHostCount1 = 1 THEN 'Found'
       WHEN @myHostCount1 = 0 THEN 'Not Found'
    END AS 'Result', 
    @myHostName4 AS 'HostName'
```

Output:

```
Result      Machine Name
--------------------------
Found       Machine220054
Not Found   Machine22054
```

Comment: What have you tried so far in c#?

Comment: JeremyRock - In c# I only have it listing machines that are found. So for example if someone gives me a list of 200 machines and it only finds 195, it will only list the 195, it won't list the 5 that it didn't find.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```sql
DECLARE @myHostName2  as Varchar(50) = 'Machine220054';
DECLARE @myHostName4  as Varchar(50) = 'Machine22054';

DECLARE @hostName TABLE (
    Name VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO @hostName (Name)
VALUES (@myHostName2), (@myHostName4)

SELECT HostName = HostName.name,
       Result   = IIF(COUNT(*) = 0, 'Not Found', 'Found')
FROM @hostName AS HostName
LEFT JOIN db_owner.host ON host.name LIKE '%' + HostName.Name + '%'
GROUP BY HostName.name;
```

Comment: That only returns the  Machine220054 as found, it doesn't show the other machine not being found - 

Result      Machine Name
--------------------------
Found       Machine220054
Not Found   Machine22054

Comment: There is a left join?

Comment: This doesn't work and doesn't produce the output I want.

Answer (score 0):

First: Try to remove as much procedural logic in SQL as possible.
Second: Try to minimize the use of "Like" queries if at all possible. It will hinder indexing and cause bottlenecks eventually, or, at least limit it to ending with a "%" instead of starting it with one.
Third: you are assuming that there will only be zero or one hit in your code. What if (given either non-unique or like based queries) there are more than one?

I'd go for something like this:

```
declare @looking table (name varchar(50))

insert into @looking (name) values ('Machine220054'),('Machine22054')
   select case when t.name is null then 'Not Found' else 'Found' end as [FoundOrNot], t.name as [FoundName],l.name as [SearchName]
          from @looking as l 
                     left outer join db_owner.host as t 
                             on t.name like '%' + l.name + '%'
```

UPDATE: Tested against a random table, removed "group by" on account of either one or no hit expected.

Comment: Getting errors near 'as' third line - Each machine name is unique so there either one  or none always.

Comment: The error was a missing "end" for the "case". Still: are you actually looking for "part of name" or is "starts with" enough? If the search criteria will match more than one record, there will still be more than one hit though, becuase of the "like". I removed the "group by" clause based on the expected one/zero condition, but be sure to test against e.g. "MACHINE1" and "MACHINE11" searches when both are present!

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide an update, I ended up taking the results from the DR reader and entering them into a datatable, since the dr reader can only be read once. Then I compared the selections from the listbox with the contents from the datatable  then added the difference to another datatable  then displayed the results in a datagrid, this produced the desired outcome of results found, being listed and the objects not found being listed as not found.